# Javascript closures and scope issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I can't wrap my head around javascript closures. I want 4 random numbers, but only get the the last one replicated 4 times.

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {      

  function setNewNumber(element) {
    return function (newNumber) {
      element.text(newNumber);
    }
  }

  $('.number').each(function() {
      $.get('http://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new', 
        setNewNumber($(this))
      );
  });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="number"></div>
<div class="number"></div>
<div class="number"></div>
<div class="number"></div>
```

[A working plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pne7kVwwnB1G6hQriM9T)

Any hints?

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa.. You know JavaScript can generate it's own random numbers right?

Comment: @Aesthete: Sure, *pseudo*-random ones. random.org does the *real thing*.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: It depends on whether random.org supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) and allows all origins.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Sure. Gotta ask though, I've seen people do stranger things!

Comment: The `num=` option seems to allow multiple numbers to be returned. So you could simply use the `.length` of the `.number` elements, and then make a single request, and split and loop the result. http://jsfiddle.net/RYTgV/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `get` request is being cached.

http://jsfiddle.net/hCEbd/1/

(That is to say your understanding of closures is correct and the code is working correctly).

From comments, because this is relevant:

> You can request multiple numbers from random.org at the same timer per their API. Instead of using four requests, use `num=' + $(".number").length` and then do a little parsing

Comment: "The get request is being cached." --- http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/random_number.png ;-)

Comment: Thanks! This saved my day! One note is that it works better with +Math.random() instead of +(new Date).getTime() since the timestamp may with big probability have the same value twice in a row.

Comment: @kvaale You can request multiple numbers from random.org at the same timer per their API.  Instead of using four requests, use `num=' + $(".number").length` and then do a little parsing

Answer (score 0):

It's a little confusing what you're trying to achieve with your top functions. If all you want to do is set the new random number to the element, you don't need either of them.

Use `ajax` to specify a few parameters to your request. In particular, you want to stop caching of your request. You can also supply a context to reference your `.number` element.

```
$('.number').each(function() {
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'http://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new',
      context: this,
      success: function(data) { 
        $(this).text(data); 
      },
      cache: false
  });
});
```

This solution fiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/VDwyg/)

Comment: Even your intent does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/hCEbd/2/ -- however, `$(this)` in the ajax callback is the jqXHR, not the element.

Comment: I mean `this` in the callback, but `$()` on the jqXHR is not useful

Comment: @ExplosionPills - You're right, fiddled a bit and modified the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Works: http://plnkr.co/edit/XTOI20kGbFbzdtDaqpLZ

Your request is being cached. By the way, getting data in cycle - it's not a good idea.

Comment: yes, I said that already...

Comment: @Explosion Pills, actually, we said it at the same time

Comment: Stackoverflow won't get specific enough because of the amount of time that has passed, but I remember that your answer was *eight minutes* after mine.  If your answer were within one to two minutes, I wouldn't have said anything, but an exact duplicate answer after that amount of time should be deleted by the owner in my opinion.  (By the way it was not me that downvoted you).

Comment: I do not understand why my answer has to be removed. I do not pretend to first place and I upvoted your answer. By the way, the answer is not entirely the same - it can be seen through the code that I wrote, when you have already answered the question (but I opened the page with the question before your answer appeared). I wish you joys and laughter. :)

Answer (score -1):

Any jquery ajax request, like $.get, changes the scope. If you want to reuse your setNewWord function it needs to be either be globally scoped or scoped in the result of the get.

Take a look at the jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/justengland/hJnXb/2/

```
function setNewWord(element) {
$('#output').append(element + '<br>');
```

}

$(function () {

```
$(numbers).each(function () {
    var url = 'http://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new';
    $.get(url, setNewWord);
});
```

});